# Is there a way to change the icon of a ClickOnce application in 'Add or Remove Programs'?

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, clickonce

I have one Windows application which is deployed using [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) technology. Is there a way to change the icon of that application which is shown in the image?

[image: Screenshot of the installer in action with a marker for the icon.]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927109/icon-for-click-once-app-in-add-or-remove-programs

Comment: Great..Post what worked for you instead of posting the link..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is what I used for solving the problem. I used Stack Overflow question *[Custom icon for ClickOnce application in 'Add or Remove Programs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927109/icon-for-click-once-app-in-add-or-remove-programs)*.

```
    private static void SetAddRemoveProgramsIcon()
    {
        //only run if deployed
        if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
             && ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun)
        {
            try
            {
                Assembly code = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                AssemblyDescriptionAttribute asdescription =
                    (AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(code, typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute));
               // string assemblyDescription = asdescription.Description;

                //the icon is included in this program
                string iconSourcePath = Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "hl772-2.ico");

                if (!File.Exists(iconSourcePath))
                    return;

                RegistryKey myUninstallKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
                string[] mySubKeyNames = myUninstallKey.GetSubKeyNames();
                for (int i = 0; i < mySubKeyNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    RegistryKey myKey = myUninstallKey.OpenSubKey(mySubKeyNames[i], true);
                    object myValue = myKey.GetValue("DisplayName");
                    if (myValue != null && myValue.ToString() == "admin")
                    {
                        myKey.SetValue("DisplayIcon", iconSourcePath);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it doesn't change the image shown at the installation window (like in the screenshot of the opening post). Does someone have a solution for that as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**: Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, WPF, C#

1. Go to Solution Explorer
2. Right-click on your ProjectName then click 'Properties'.
3. Click Application as shown below. Remember your icon name.

[image]

4. Click 'Publish' on the left column.
5. Click 'Options...' button on the right.
6. 'Publish Options' window should pop up as shown below. Remember what's in the 'Product name:' field. In the example below, it's "MyProductName"

[image]

6. Copy and paste the following code in your main class.

```
    private void SetAddRemoveProgramsIcon()
    {
        if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed && ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun)
        {
            try
            {
                var iconSourcePath = Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "MyIcon.ico");

                if (!File.Exists(iconSourcePath)) return;

                var myUninstallKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
                if (myUninstallKey == null) return;

                var mySubKeyNames = myUninstallKey.GetSubKeyNames();
                foreach (var subkeyName in mySubKeyNames)
                {
                    var myKey = myUninstallKey.OpenSubKey(subkeyName, true);
                    var myValue = myKey.GetValue("DisplayName");
                    if (myValue != null && myValue.ToString() == "MyProductName") // same as in 'Product name:' field
                    {
                            myKey.SetValue("DisplayIcon", iconSourcePath);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception uhoh)
            {
                //log exception
            }
        }
    }
```

7. Call SetAddRemoveProgramsIcon in the constructor.

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SetAddRemoveProgramsIcon();
    }
```

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath did not work for me.
I had to use System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() for my ClickOnce Installation as path for the Icon in Add and Remove Programms