# Publish WinForm that uses .dll in one file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dll, exe, software-packaging

**How can you publish a WinForm that uses a .dll extension into one .exe file?** I'm using VB.NET on Visual Studio 2013.

I have tried several methods such as using only the program .exe file from both the Debug and Release folder but these didn't work in isolation - a **runtime error happened every time a command from the extension was used**, as if it didn't exist.

My problem is packaging the entire program into one file. I don't want to have to use ClickOnce applications because you can't use a custom logo and so it kinda looks bad. I'll use it if there's no alternative.

Comment: The best way to distribute your program as a single file is in one that's called setup.exe.  Surely you've seen them before.  There are *many* installer builder utilities around, including ones that support a splash screen or logo.  You need to go shopping.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! I forgot about that one! I just meant t you can't use a custom shortcut logo and the status bar icon is fixed to this hideous icon when you're using ClickOnce

Comment: Kinda hard to miss [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245056/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-icon-of-a-clickonce-application-in-add-or-remove-p) when you google "clickonce custom icon".

Comment: <douche>For future reference: "I have tried several methods" is not really informative. Try specifying what you have tried. To me this sounds exactly the same as "I've tried to climb Mount Everest, but I didn't even leave my bed" </douche>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the answer was to use the setup.exe file when publishing. Also, changing the logo of a ClickOnce program is possible.