# How to add Icon to add or remove programmers when publishing a WPF applcation

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I am Writing a WPF Application with visual sutdio 2013.
In the properites of the application I specified an icon.
I also added it to the folder (jpg and ico)

when I publish my applicaion as offline (launchable from start menu)

I have 2 questions
1) the icon appear in the folder and when I run the application but does not appear in the add or remove programs, how can I add it to add remove programs?

2) how can I specify where I want the folder to be installed? also is there a way to add a dialog to ask the user?

Thanks for all the answers

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245056/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-icon-of-a-clickonce-application-in-add-or-remove-p)?

Comment: How do you publish? The registry stuff (add/remove entry, icons, etc.) and dialog during installation are a part of installer, which one you use?

Comment: If ClickOnce is too simple: https://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: Hi mm8 I didn't see but I am not understand where to paste this code in your link.

sinatr I publish per visual studio in the tab publish. I think it ClickOnce

Comment: Nawed Nabi Zada I will check this but I am not understand why using this if I already have in VS