# Icon for ClickOnce application in 'Add or Remove Programs'

Tags: icons, clickonce, addremoveprograms

I got the icons right for my application, in the Start Menu, application folders, etc., but it doesn't come right into the *Add or Remove Programs* listing. What should I include for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Custom icon for ClickOnce application in 'Add or Remove Programs'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927109/custom-icon-for-clickonce-application-in-add-or-remove-programs)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might not be able to do it directly through ClickOnce, as it's not supported. Maybe you could try editing the registry a bit as shown in *[Missing Icon in Add/Remove Programs for ClickOnce Application](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/db1d57ee-7743-4409-8072-f0e84ab5330a/)*:

```
RegistryKey myUninstallKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
string[] mySubKeyNames = myUninstallKey.GetSubKeyNames();

for (int i = 0; i < mySubKeyNames.Length; i++)
{
    RegistryKey myKey = myUninstallKey.OpenSubKey(mySubKeyNames , true);
    object myValue = myKey.GetValue("DisplayName");
    if (myValue != null && (string)myValue == _ApplicationName)
    {
        myKey.SetValue("DisplayIcon", _ExecutablePath + @"\App.ico");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an icon using the Windows standard property `ARPPRODUCTICON`.
In your standard Windows installer, add the following code. This will add an icon in the control panel.

```
<Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="MySourceFiles\icon.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
```

Comment: Humor me for a moment: where exactly does this code go?  Where is the standard windows installer?