# How to change wpf application default icon in control panel

Tags: .net, wpf

### How to change wpf application default icon in control panel

I am working on a wpf application.I need to set application icont.I setup it by changing the icon using application properties window.But its not changing in controlpanel.Control panel still shows default application icon.please help..

Comment: can you explain it further ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the setup project:

In the Properties Window of the setup project, the first property is [AddRemoveProgramsIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4s0kfk4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

If you use clickonce there is no easy way to do it:

You must use a registry hack: [Custom icon for ClickOnce application in 'Add or Remove Programs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927109/custom-icon-for-clickonce-application-in-add-or-remove-programs)

Comment: We are using CliCkOnce deployment..So how?