# "Programs and Features" icon for Win application (deployed with ClickOnce)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, publish, publishing

Using Visual Studio 2012, I manage to publish a Winforms application and install it successfully on other machines, making it work nicely. Although, there are a few small details that I want to change.

- The published application goes into the Start Menu inside a folder named after me. I suppose it's taking my Windows user name, I don't set it anywhere, it just happens by default. I wish I could define that.

**(EDIT)**

I solved the above issue: `Project properties > "Publish tab" > Options` and set the Publisher name: this is the name of the folder

**(end edit)**

- When I look for the program in `Control Panel > Programs and Features`, it has a weird default icon instead of the one I defined (which appears correctly on the Start Menu)

So, how to set my icon on the Programs and Features as well?

**(EDIT)** - 
I'm using ClickOnce apparently (thanks to @Crono)

Thanks

Comment: What are you deploying your application with?

Comment: Are you using Clickonce? Wix? Installshield?

Comment: I don't know: I developed the application and then, in Visual Studio 2012, Build > Publish

Comment: Then it's Clickonce. ;) I'll leave it to somebody else to provide an answer because I have little to no experience with it. If I may though, I suggest you start looking into Wix installer. It's free, it's open source and it's backed by Microsoft which itself uses it for key products. The learning curve is a lot steeper but it will give you much more power over the installation experience of your applications. www.wixtoolset.org

Answer (score 1):

For changing application icon in `Programs and Features`, this answer might help you: [Custom icon for ClickOnce application in 'Add or Remove Programs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927109/custom-icon-for-clickonce-application-in-add-or-remove-programs)

The trick is in adding a registry string value `DisplayIcon` pointing to the icon file. The value is located under `Uninstall` registry key of your application.